# Use of siunitx, beamer and \maketitle simultaneously?

Tags: beamer, titles, siunitx

I'm using `beamer` and I'm not able to use the package `siunitx` features within the `\maketitle` environment. Minimal NOT working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\title{\SI{5}{\micro \ampere}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the [log](https://pastee.org/6sjm6%22log%22).

Any suggestions?

Comment: The maintainers of `siunitx` and `beamer` are unable to talk to each other. ;-)

Comment: Move the `\title` command after `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands of `siunitx` producing unit symbols are only defined after `\begin{document}`; you have two choices: typing

```
\title{\unexpanded{\SI{5}{\micro\ampere}}}
```

or moving

```
\title{\SI{5}{\micro\ampere}}
```

after `\begin{document}`.

I guess the latter method is easier.